How may $\Vvdash$ be negated?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}
How may $\Vvdash$ be negated just as $\vdash$ is negated by $\nvdash$?
\end{document}


There is no predefined negated version of \Vvdash. You can use \not\Vvdash, but the spacing is off given the chosen font. I would instead use \cancel{\Vvdash}, where the \cancel command is from the cancel package.
